# Attaching a number to the end of variable php

Tags: php, html

Probably another basic question but its been annoying me for a while now...

I have a php file which is included on a php web page to bring in dynamic content from my mysql database.

Everything works fine with this except when i try get pictures to work and here is the problem.

I am using the code:

```
echo "<img src=fishery_images/$region/$url/$url1.jpg'/>";
```

All of which has been selected from the correct table and so on. an example of what i want this to resolve to is below:

```
fishery_images/fife/goldenloch/goldenloch1.jpg
```

However because i have the code:

```
$url1.jpg
```

and `$url1` is not defined as anything then it resolves as the following:

```
fishery_images/fife/goldenloch/.jpg
```

i can have anything from goldenloch1.jpg all the way to goldenloch10.jpg so need to be able to say which image should be used.

how is it i say `$url1.jpg` without meaning `$url1`?

Really hope this makes sense... and thanks in advance

Comment: `echo "<img src=fishery_images/$region/$url/$url".$your_number_variable.".jpg'/>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<img src=fishery_images/{$region}/{$url}/{$url}1.jpg'/>";
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#PHP

Comment: Does this present the same as `echo "<img src='fishery_images/" . $region . "/" . $url . "/" . $url . "1.jpg'/>";`?

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfect. One question about this website.. and i dont know if this is the correct place to ask.. but if i have a questiont thats been on for a while and doent yet have an accepted answer.. is it likely to ever get answered? I am just concerned because it was posted on March 30th and wont appear any where near the top of the questions section?

Comment: I've never known this syntax, I've always done it by escaping the variables, this will save me a lot of time. Any technical differences between these 2 uses?

Comment: andrew, I'm not really sure. I'm new around here too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use curly braces to wrap your variable:

```
echo "<img src=fishery_images/$region/$url/{$url}1.jpg'/>";
```

Comment: `$url` is the variable that's defined. `$url1` is undefined. And it may pay to be consistent with the braces.